# Reader monad transformer sample with FSharpPlus

Tags: f#, monad-transformers, f#+

I'm trying to understand the reader monad transformer. I'm using [FSharpPlus](https://fsprojects.github.io/FSharpPlus/) and try to compile the following sample which first reads something from the reader environment, then performs some async computation and finally combines both results:

```ml
open FSharpPlus
open FSharpPlus.Data

let sampleReader = monad {
    let! value = ask
    return value * 2
}

let sampleWorkflow = monad {
    do! Async.Sleep 5000
    return 4
}

let doWork = monad {
    let! envValue = sampleReader
    let! workValue = liftAsync sampleWorkflow
    return envValue + workValue
}

ReaderT.run doWork 3 |> Async.RunSynchronously |> printfn "Result: %d"
```

With this I get a compilation error at the line where it says `let! value = ask` with the following totally unhelpful (at least for me) error message:

> Type constraint mismatch when applying the default type 'obj' for a type inference variable. No overloads match for method 'op_GreaterGreaterEquals'.
>
> Known return type: Async
>
> Known type parameters: < obj , (int -> Async) >

It feels like I'm just missing some operator somewhere, but I can't figure it out.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your code is correct, but F# type inference is not that smart in cases like this.

If you add a type annotation to sampleReader it will compile fine:

```
let sampleReader : ReaderT<int,Async<_>> = monad {
    let! value = ask
    return value * 2
}

// val sampleReader : FSharpPlus.Data.ReaderT<int,Async<int>> =
//  ReaderT <fun:sampleReader@7>
```

**Update**:

After reading your comments.
If what you want is to make it generic, first of all your function has to be declared `inline` otherwise type constraints can't be applied:

`let inline sampleReader  = monad ...`

But that takes you to the second problem: a constant can't be declared inline (actually there is a way but it's too complicated) only functions can.

So the easiest is to make it a function:

`let inline sampleReader () = monad ...`

And now the third problem the code doesn't compile :)

Here again, you can give type inference a minimal hint, just to say at the call site that you expect a `ReaderT<_,_>` will be enough:

```
let inline sampleReader () = monad {
    let! value = ask
    return value * 2
}

let sampleWorkflow = monad {
    do! Async.Sleep 5000
    return 4
}

let doWork = monad {
    let! envValue = sampleReader () : ReaderT<_,_>
    let! workValue = liftAsync sampleWorkflow
    return envValue + workValue
}

ReaderT.run doWork 3 |> Async.RunSynchronously |> printfn "Result: %d"
```

**Conclusion**:

Defining a generic function is not that trivial task in F#.
If you look into the source of F#+ you'll see what I mean.

After running your example you'll see all the constraints being generated and you'll probably noted how the compile-time increased by making your function inline and generic.

These are all indications that we're pushing F# type system to the limits.

Although F#+ defines some ready-to-use generic functions, and these functions can sometimes be combined in such a way that you create your own generic functions, that's not the goal of the library, I mean you can but then you're on your own, in some scenarios like exploratory development it might make sense.

Comment: Oh nice, good enough, thanks. I wonder why I have to include `Async<_>` though, can `sampleReader` only be used with `async`s? I mean why doesn't it work with both `Async<_>` and say `Option<_>`? This seems to be a limitation of FSharpPlus, right?

Comment: Oh I see. I just updated the answer. Hope this helps.

Comment: Perfect, thanks for the detailed update. Although all in all not as satisfying as I hoped, I'm happy to know that it's as good as it gets in F#.